# find the position of old ortophotos cv2 python

Tags: python-3.x, image

I have thousands of old ortophotos without positional information. I tried stitching them using cv2 Python. It worked quite well.

Now I'm unable to find the coordinated position and scale for the photos. I tried template match, but it did not work well because the old photos do not have scale and match usually did not work. In template match I used for new coordinated photo as base. Has anyone experienced this?